# Visual studio asks for runat server tag on a component that alreayd has it

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runatserver

TextBox1 must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server is the error I get, my code is as follows.

```
<div >

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
```

I was wondering why I get this error, and how I can fix it.

Comment: The error indicates it has to be inside a `<form>` tag, does it not?  You don't have a `form` tag.

Comment: yes, I noticed it after asking the question, lready fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking for a **<form>** element:

```
<form runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="User" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yep, a little after posting this thread I came to thsi conclussion while reading my code, I forgot to add the form that inherits all my CS stuff, thank you.